Configure UPS RequestShipment to bill connected account
I’ve already implemented the UPS API for oauth but once that accounts connected, how do I request a shipping label and set the required billing param to bill the default payment method on their account?
I either have to enter a credit card number or an account number but I can’t access the account number via the api.

If you are looking to create labels and you are the shipper, the bill will be associated with the UPS account itself. In the create shipment API, you can directly add PaymentInformation object. Your account number should already be available to you; you can look at the account information inside your UPS account.
"PaymentInformation": {
            "ShipmentCharge": {
                "Type": "01",
                "BillShipper": {
                    "AccountNumber": "132312"
                }
            }
        }

This is how you can associate the billing in your shipment create API.
Hope this solves the issue.
